"Experiencing Difficulty Connecting OnePlus Nord Buds2 to Ubuntu 22.04
I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my Ubuntu 22.04 setup and OnePlus Nord Buds2. While these earbuds function flawlessly with my Mac and Android devices (utilizing AAC), they're proving to be a bit finicky with Ubuntu.
Here's the rundown: My Ubuntu system, powered by PulseAudio, typically handles other Bluetooth devices with ease, connecting via A2DP and delivering excellent sound quality. However, when attempting to pair the Nord Buds2, they inexplicably default to Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) mode.
I've exhausted a range of troubleshooting steps, including attempts to install AAC (unsuccessfully, as it doesn't appear in PulseAudio options), cycling Bluetooth services, performing device resets, and even resorting to full system restarts. Despite these efforts, the issue persists.
At this juncture, my last resort seems to be transitioning to PipeWire. However, I'm hesitant to make the switch without confirmation that it'll resolve the problem.
Has anyone else faced similar challenges with Bluetooth earbuds on Ubuntu 22.04? If so, were you able to find a solution? Your insights and guidance would be immensely appreciated!"
